# What are the main glaring differences between the JVM and KVM?

Tags: java, jvm, kvm

I'm learning Java for a course this month, and this question is just one I thought of that I'd like to know.

What are the main differences between these two? I know KVM is targeted for mobile devices, correct?

Comment: Well, a JVM is a virtual machine for Java, and a KVM is for controlling multiple computers with a single keyboard/monitor/mouse (not simultaneously, mind you)... :P

Comment: I almost spit up my coffee after reading the above response.

Comment: Until just now, I had no idea there was a definition of KVM other than Bears's.

Answer (score 3):

The KVM is specifically optimized for use with devices with 128k - 256k available memory. It is developed for use with J2ME. The JVM has additional libraries and functionality that the KVM does not have out of the box (but these libraries can be added to the KVM as needed).

[More information on the KVM and J2ME.](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis.jsp)